# How to rename this column using AS for display

Tags: sql-server

Im trying to rename this as `DOC`:

```
Select Distinct 
    a.CID,
    CONCAT (RTRIM(Name1), ' ', RTRIM(Name2)) As [Name of Policy Holder],
    InsuStartDate = cast(InsuStartDate as date), --> DOC
```

What is the possible way to rename `InsuStartDate` as `DOC` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use as below-

```
Select Distinct 
a.CID,
CONCAT (RTRIM(Name1), ' ', RTRIM(Name2)) As [Name of Policy Holder],
DOC = cast(InsuStartDate as date)
```

OR

```
Select Distinct 
a.CID,
CONCAT (RTRIM(Name1), ' ', RTRIM(Name2)) As [Name of Policy Holder],
cast(InsuStartDate as date) DOC
```